# Noetherian induction; closed sets that are not finite union of irreducibles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, induction, noetherian

I am following an online course on algebraic geometry. On today's lesson, the lecturer stated the following theorem: Any Noetherian space is a finite union of irreducible subspaces. For the proof, he takes C to be the minimal element of the set of those closed subsets that cannot be represented as a finite union of irreducibles. He then automatically assumes that C has to be reducible, because he says that C irreducible automatically leads to a contradiction. I don't see why this happens. I have proved that C cannot be irreducible (and also that it cannot be irreducible) and therefore the theorem is proved, but I don't see why this happens immediately; it took me a few lines to do it.

Comment: An irreducible element is a finite union of irreducible elements. So saying, it cannot be represented as a finite union of ...

Comment: @DietrichBurde an irreducible element is a finite union of irreducible elements? That does not make much sense, right?

Comment: Oh yes, it does make sense. A union of sets $S=S_1\cup S_2\cup\cdots \cup S_n$ makes sense for $n=1$. Then $S$ is just $S_1$, the "trivial" union.

Answer (score 1):

$C$ was taken as the minimal element from a certain set. Think about what defines the elements of that set, and why not just $C$, but *all* elements in that set must be reducible.

Comment: So an element of that set is either an finite union of reducibles (and thus reducible) or an inifinite union of irreducibles (thus irreducible)

Comment: An element from that set "cannot be represented as a finite union of irreducibles." An irreducible set itself obviously can be represented that way. So the set can contain only reducible sets.

Comment: Okay I see. I don't know why I was assuming that it had to be a finite union of proper subsets. Thank you!